# How to make like and unlike

Tags: mysql, ajax

I have tried to make like and like system using ajax and mysql.
Click like, like is added and Click again, like min 1.
I want, when I click unlike, it will back to like.
But this, unlike until minus..

This is my mysql

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    session_start();
    $ip=$_SESSION['id'];
    if ($_POST['id'])
       {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $ip_sql=mysql_query("select id_user from social where track_id='$id' and       id_user='$ip'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);
    if ($count==0)
    {
        $sql = "update track set jumlah_like=jumlah_like+1 where track_id='$id'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        $sql_in = "insert into social (id_user,track_id) values ('$ip','$id')";
        mysql_query($sql_in);
        $result=mysql_query("select jumlah_like from track where track_id='$id'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $love=$row['jumlah_like'];

?>  
        <span class="broke_love" align="left"><?php echo $love; ?></span>
<?php
}
else
{
        $sql = "update track set jumlah_like=jumlah_like-1 where track_id='$id'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        //$sql_in = "insert into social (id_user,track_id) values ('$ip','$id')";
        //mysql_query($sql_in);
        $result=mysql_query("select jumlah_like from track where track_id='$id'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $love=$row['jumlah_like'];
        echo "<span class=on_img align=left>$love</span>";
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: First off, you should use `isset` function to check your `$_POST['id']` variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is algorithmic that is causing your button to be stuck on 'unlike'.

Your basic condition is: `if ($count==0)` which always returns greater than 0 after the statement `$sql_in = "insert into social (id_user,track_id) values ('$ip','$id')"; is run.`

Therefore, your code gets stuck in always executing the else, and continously diminishing the likes.

You need to change your logic to be more:

- Check if likes exist and add for specific user.
- If like already exists, remove like record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something from your script as you do not appear to remove a record from the table social.

However most of your selects and updates can be done with a single piece of SQL. Something 
like:-

```
UPDATE track a
LEFT OUTER JOIN social b ON a.track_id = b.track_id AND id_user='$ip'
SET a.jumlah_like = a.jumlah_like + IF(b.track_id IS NULL, 1, -1)
```

It would probably be better to have a votes table rather than adding and deleting records on the social table. One row per vote.